# Method code not executing in the correct order

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, svprogresshud

I have two methods. One method is used to load my SVProgressHUD, the second method is used to get data from my coreData and sort it then present it in a new UITableView. The user selects are UITableViewCell which calls:

> didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Then I have two method calls in this, the first is:

> [self loadHUD];

This method loads a hud (which never shows if I implement the second method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath). This is the second method:

> [self loadAndSortArray];

When I call this for some reason it is preventing the SVProgressHud from ever appearing, however if I remove this method call then the hud loads fine.

I would like to know how I can have both methods but display the hud before the second method starts ?

Comment: I'd suggest digging into the call that actually displays the HUD and see how it is implemented. It is probably scheduling an invocation asynchronously, perhaps with some condition that is not being met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the views are refreshed in the main thread, if you don't put expensive process like `loadAndSortArray` in background thread this happen to you.

You can put that method inside:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    [self loadAndSortArray];
});
```